# "Be first to review" not getting displayed (Magento version 1.9)

Tags: magento-1.9, review

I have replaced Review template from rwd default theme

So review tab is getting displayed on my custom theme, on view page.

But the link "Be first to review" is not getting displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check in your `view.phtml` file

```
<?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'default', false)?>
```

if for that product anyone has posted review than `Be first to review` this text wont come instead review count will come.

Comment: You are always welcome,  as Always :)